# Reading default JVM property using program

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments, jdk6

I am trying to read current entity expansion`Djdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit` limit, but it is giving null.
I tried the following code

```
System.getProperty("Djdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit");
System.getProperty("jdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit");
System.getProperty("jdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit");
System.getProperty("-DentityExpansionLimit");
System.getProperty("-Djdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit");
System.getProperty("ENTITY_EXPANSION_LIMIT");
```

All are giving result as `null`

Comment: How are you running your program? How are you trying to set these system properties?

Comment: Are you sure its `Djdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit` not `jdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit`

Answer (score 0):

You run your program like

`java Example -Djdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit=1234`

and read this property like

`System.getProperty("jdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit");`

Answer (score 0):

You can list out all properties and check its name:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
Enumeration keys = props.keys();
while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
  String key = (String)keys.nextElement();
  String value = (String)props.get(key);
  System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
}
```

If you can't see it, I think that property is not set before.
Hope this helps.